# Create auth attribute for MVC and WebAPI with session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have MVC 4 controllers for UI (angularjs) and some subset of WebAPI controllers for data management with UI. I need to add authentication handler or both of them:

```
class MySuperAuthAttribute{}

[MySuperAuth]
public class MyWebApiController{}

[MySuperAuth]
public class MyWebMvcController{}
```

In auth handler i need just to check if user is in some group. And also i'd like to store this information (that user is authenticated) in a current session

In my attribute's handler i can write somthing like `UserProvider.CheckInGroup(userName)`.

How should i store this result and use it in the next call?

For example:

```
if (HttpContext.Session['MY_AUTH_KEY'] != null && HttpContext.Session["MY_AUTH_KEY"] == "OK") {
    return true;
}
else {
    if (UserProvider.CheckInGroup(userName))
        HttpContext.Session['MY_AUTH_KEY'] = "OK";
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are clear enough on your question but in your attribute you can access the session using

```
HttpContext.Current.Session
```

Just need a reference to System.Web to have that.

Comment: and the current way of Session+Auth usage in ASP will be to manually store authentication result in session? Or is there some automation for auth action?

Comment: For auth action now you need to have your attribute extend AuthorizeAttribute (inherit it) and in there access the session .. So just make sure that your attribute inherit AuthorizeAttribute and handle the AuthorizeCore method.